# Basic fileread question in PHP /

Tags: php, xml, file, csv

I have a 12 XML files from which I am extracting ONE CSV file, from which - I am extracting column 1 and appending values to a tt.txt   file .

NOW, I need to extract the values from this .txt file... everytime data is written to it ...
But the problem is , when I use

> $contents = fread ($fd,filesize ($filename));
>   fclose ($fd);
>   $delimiter = ',' ;
>   $splitcontents = explode($delimiter, $contents);

IT reads ONLY from the first value of the file , every time a tt.txt file is appended !

I hope u understand the problem .. What I need is , I want $contents to have only the new data that was appended... instead it reads from the start of the file everytime...

Is there a way to achieve this, or does php fail ?/

> This prob is extraction from TXT file- > performing computations- > writing INTO a new txt file . The problem being that I can't read from a middle value to a new value.. PHP always reads from the start of a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to store the last file position.

Call filesize to get current length, read the file, later, check if filesize is different (or maybe you know this some other way, and use fseek to move the cursor in the file, then read from there.

IE:

```
$previousLength = 0;

// your loop when you're calling your new read function
$length = filesize($filename);
fseek($fd,$previousLength);
$contents = fread($fd,$length - $previousLength);
$previousLength = $length;
```

Comment: Hey, NO it doesn't work.... It always STARTS reading from the start... I want it to read from $length - $prevlength to NEWLENGTH !!

Comment: I am badly lookin for a solution.. help !

Comment: IT's probably that fseek isn't storing the last file position ... I need to use some other function ? like ftruncate ?

Comment: I needed to use > fseek($fd,$previousLength,$previousLength);  .. int whence specifies start pos ... . BUT, it still didn't work ...

Answer (score 0):

It is only reading the first field because PHP does not automatically assume that a newline character (`\n`) means a new record; you have to handle this, yourself.

Using what you already have, I would do the following:

```
$contents = fread($fd, filesize($filename));
close($fd);

/* Now, split up $contents by newline, turning this into an array, where each element
 * is, in effect, a new line in the CSV file. */
$contents = explode("\n", $contents);

/* Now, explode each element in the array, into itself. */
foreach ($contents as &$c) {
   $c = explode(",", $c);
}
```

In the future, if you want to go line-by-line, as you run the risk of hogging too many resources by reading the *entire* file in, use [`fgets()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php).

Comment: Thanks man,, but I am reading from a text file delimited by a comma and writing to a new text file to generat data for a graph ... Is this code for writing it directly from the csv file ? I mean what is $fd in this code... txt or csv ?

Comment: This prob is extraction from TXT file- >  performing computations- > writing INTO a new txt file .   The problem being that I can't read from a middle value to a new value.. PHP always reads from the start of a file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not great at arrays but it sounds to me like you need an associative array (I'm doing a similar thing with the following code. 
     $lines = explode("\n", $contents);

```
foreach ($lines as $line) {

 $parts = explode(',', $line);
    if (count($parts) > 0) {
           $posts = array();
        $posts[] = array('name' => $parts[3],'email' => $parts[4],'phone' =>           $parts[5],'link' => $parts[6],'month' => $parts[0],'day' => $parts[1],'year' =>    $parts[2]);      }


     foreach ($posts as $post):
            $post = array_filter(array_map('trim', $post));
```

Comment: in this example you break each line into parts exploding at the comma and give each part a variable name as $post[newvariablename]